# How do I record audio and video screen-capture for Tutorials on DAWs with ScreenFlow?

Tags: video, audio

My question might be a bit too specific, but essentially I'm trying to create my own tutorial material of **How-To's** in Propellerhead Reason 6. I'm using ScreenFlow as my Screen-recording software.

So my process has been overly complicated at this point (and I'm sure there's ways to simplify it), which involves:

- Properly booting up the right software in the right sequence (Reason 6, JackServer, ScreenFlow);
- Taking like 5mins to properly configure / map the routings between Reason 6 and JackServer's inputs and outputs (including monitor-outputs enabled to loop back into a Reason 6 Audio Track).
- Start ScreenFlow, configure the recording settings to capture only screen video, no audio;
- While the count-down starts (from ScreenFlow), I jump back in Reason 6, make sure the monitoring Audio Track is armed, and start recording my Mic and all sounds emitted during my session;
- AFTER that is all done, I stop recording in both applications, have to export the WAV from Reason 6, import it into ScreenFlow.... and then video composite / editing begins!

The thing that sucks with ScreenFlow, although it does allow JackServer as a sound-source, it DOESN'T actually capture any sound.

Is there any way to cut down on the amount of "fudging-around" with Audio drivers / Aggregate Devices or SoundFlower(bed) just for the sake of capturing audio from Reason 6 directly into ScreenFlow without having to import a separately recorded WAV file?

I'm hoping for an answer that won't tell me I have to buy YET another software or piece of hardware. But if it's free, perfect! :)

Thanks!

NOTE: My Audio Interface is a MOTU-Traveler, operating on Mac OSX Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although this violates a bit my request of not using SoundFlower(bed) or Aggregate Devices, on Mac OSX's Audio MIDI settings, if you create an Aggregate Device with your Audio Interface hardware AND Soundflower (2-channels), you should be able to "feed" into it from your DAW and "listen" to SoundFlower from ScreenFlow.

Here's a Video Tutorial that shows how I've accomplished this, using this very technique to record this video! :)

This example shows how to route things up in a Record & Reason scenario. Other DAWs should be able to do something similar, since they usually allow you to pick which Audio device you want to output to.

Comment: Haven't tried this one yet, but I think I will switch from using SoundFlower to WireTap Pro. Looks like it's been discontinued and available for free! Available for Mac: http://wiretap-pro.en.softonic.com/mac/download

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I've been doing this by recording WITHIN the DAW and then syncing the tracks. You could even do this by creating some noise in the DAW that also has a visual aspect (e.g., turning a synth on and off).

I'm working with Ableton Live and a video camera (and an iPad, to be honest), but same difference. Results here:

This is a PITA but you sync the tracks ONCE, generally. I actually do it with a clap on both recordings, then turn off the input track that has the clap on the DAW to do the rest of the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

So far I've only found this one alternative suggested by a user of ScreenFlow:

http://blogs.telestream.net/screenflow/2010/09/how-to-route-daw-audio-into-screenflow/

He suggest to download **WireTap Anywhere**, which has a 30-day trial.

http://www.ambrosiasw.com/utilities/wta

But this still isn't a free solution, and considering I already bought ScreenFlow, I don't feel like tossing money in the fire by purchasing WTA for $129.00USD which will only act as a middle-man between the DAW and ScreenFlow.

My only free alternative at this point might have to be to patch my MOTU Traveler back into itself and have ScreenFlow listen to that Stereo channel input. ***Argggh!!***

Comment: Not sure if the Motu has an optical in and out, but that could work. Note: I've tried this with a cheap Roland Edirol interface once upon a time with no success. Soundflower is fine, just remember to bypass is when the movie-making is over :)